# Inno Setup - no 64 Bit data type?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal, freepascal

"Inno-Setup Compiler" doesn't know the pascal data type "QWord". Is there a 64 Bit equivalent to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct type available for 64-bit unsigned integer type in Inno Setup at this time. Starting from Inno Setup 5.5.3 Unicode the `Int64` type was introduced, but it's a signed 64-bit integer, whilst [`QWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230362.aspx) needs to be an unsigned 64-bit integer.

Comment: So? UInt64 now?